# repquota for single user

Tags: ubuntu, quota

My users on ubuntu server has quota enabled. And I can list current information with repquota. This prints information for all users. Is it possible to request quota information for particular user? (|grep  - is not an option)

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`repquota`(8) is not the command for this: It's designed to operate on the whole filesystem, not the stuff owned by an individual user/group.

You want to use `quota`(1) instead. Something like `quota -u myuser` will do what you want.
See [the manpage](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/quota/329444/), specifically the `-u` (user) option, for more details.